# Windows Preview Handler using FMX drawing functions?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have created an FMX graphics application that draws various graphics from a custom binary vector file format. I'd now like to create a Windows Preview Handler to support that file format. I have already created a basic VCL preview handler based on the code found [here](https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2011/06/01/windows-7-previews-the-delphi-way/). Some minor fixes were needed to get it to build in Delphi 10.4. I have also added a TPaintBox that I can draw to using the VCL TCanvas drawing functions.

The problem is that all the drawing for my file format is using FMX and uses several functions that don't exist in VCL, such as colour gradients and opacity. Is it possible to somehow mix in FMX TCanvas code for the preview handler?

If not then I have another option, but I'm not sure how well it would work. I would add functionality to the FMX application such that executing it with the appropriate input parameters (file path and dimensions) would generate an image file. The preview handler would just need to call it and load the image to display it. This would mean that the preview handler could be VCL only and would also reduce code size by not replicating the drawing code, but there may be latency issues.

I could also potentially use GDI+ or Direct2D in a VCL application since it would also support the advanced drawing functions, but it would mean rewriting all the drawing functions and I'm not sure if it would look exactly the same.

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Both GDI and GDI+ are very old. Direct2D is the modern Win32 2D graphics API. (My main reason for abandoning GDI is that GDI curves aren't anti-aliased.)

Comment: You could use your FMX code to draw to an in-memory bitmap, then copy the bitmap to the VCL canvas.

Comment: Thanks Olivier. Can you give more details? How would the memory be shared between separate applications?

Comment: Can't you put the rendering code directly inside the preview handler?

Comment: Olivier, the problem is that the rendering code is FMX. The preview handler is VCL. I don't know how to combine the two. Even if I could it would make the preview handler quite a large file. I could use GDI+ instead but I would need to translate all the drawing functions. This is the options I'm heading towards currently though I think.

Comment: @XylemFlow "*I don't know how to combine the two*" - VCL and FMX are not meant to be mixed together.  Can't you simply re-write the preview handler in FMX?

Comment: Preview handlers are dlls that need to interface with the Windows Api. Is this possible in FMX? I've not been able to find any examples.

Comment: If you can create an in-memory bitmap with FMX and access the pixel data, then it should be possible to copy those pixels to a GDI context (with [`SetPixel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setpixel)).